# Using OCaml for ARM (android/ios) as a C interface library

Tags: ios, c, linux, arm, ocaml

I want to use this [MirageOS TCP/IP stack written in OCaml](https://github.com/mirage/mirage-tcpip) on my app. My app is meant to work on Linux, macOS, Windows, Android, iOS.

According to https://ocaml.org/learn/portability.html, x86 support is ok for Windows, macOS, Linux. However, for ARM, it only lists Linux (Android maybe?).

*My project is mainly in C++. The reason I want to use a OCaml TCP/IP stack is that this one is very simple, portable, and can be easily audited, and also is much safer than C-style libs which suffer from buffer overflows and other vulnerabilities related to having states, something which is mitigated by functional languages. There's also no portable and simple C/C++ TCP/IP stacks (I've inspected some on github).*

I've found these 2 efforts to bring OCaml for mobile:

https://github.com/ocaml-cross/opam-cross-android

https://github.com/ocaml-cross/opam-cross-ios

But they're quite old. I also don't have experience in OCaml porting although I understand funcional languages.

I just want to use OCaml code as a library from my C++ code to interact with. I think this is much easier than trying to make pure OCaml apps.

I'd like to ask if anyone knows how to make those toolchains to work with modern OCaml so I can bring the MirageOS TCP/IP stack and compile it for mobile.

Comment: linux has a tcp/ip stack already (for all platforms) what is wrong with the stock stack?

Comment: if running linux then how is this an arm question?

Comment: @old_timer I'm calling OpenVPN library by myself in userspace, no TUN/TAP required. OpenVPN3 delivers IP packets, so I need an IP stack

Comment: @old_timer I want to run on iOS, which is ARM

Comment: then why the linux tag?

Comment: @old_timer because I wanted to try to use the linux generated .so for ARM in iOS